# template identifier vs decltype in template function parameter type

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, decltype

What do you consider as better?

```
template <typename T> void func(T x,T y) {}
```

or

```
template <typename T> void func(T x,decltype(x) y) {}
```

IMHO, the second form seems preferable because the link in between the types of x and y is explicit, and at least when renaming the template identifier things seems less error-prone.

**EDIT**

Second form let you call the function with a subtype of the one use for the first parameter, while the first form needs the exact same types. This argument seems slightly better than previous one.

Comment: The second form also seems unnecessary obfuscated.

Comment: I don't really get the use-case for the `decltype` alternative. Care to elaborate on why you want something like that?

Comment: Wouldn't the second form enable implicit conversions for `y`, while the first one doesn't?

Comment: @Quentin never thought about this, need to dig...

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès the operand of `decltype` is indeed a [non-deduced context](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I edited the question because there is a big difference, as different calls are allowed.

Comment: For that matter, if you want to be explicit `template <typename T1, typename T2, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T1, T2>{}>> void func(T1 x, T2 y) {}`. Note that there are may be subtle differences between all these options when the types are deduces. This option and the first of your options have the advantage that they are symmetric with respect to x, y, which I don't think it is true for the `decltype` version.

Comment: @alfc Yes I noticed that, not symmetric.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès, maybe you *don't* want it to be symmetric, it depends on your application. I think the decltype version is similar to `template<typename T> void func(T x, typename identity<T>::type y){}`. So, it is not a matter of what is more correct or more explicit, but a matter of what do you want to achieve. The two options are semantically different, although in many context they will behave similarly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are semantically different, so it depends on what you want to achieve. The second is more restrictive than the first. Consider:

```
template <typename T> void func1(T x, decltype(x) y) {}
template <typename T> void func2(T x, T y) {}

func1(2., 4); // converts 4 to double
func2(2., 4); // fails to compile
```

In SFINAE contexts it can lead to different compile-time behavior (not necessarely a compilation error), and the two options indirectly can compile to different programs.

Answer (score 2):

Both forms don't mean *exactly* the same. The second one is non-deduced.

The first one also won't allow implicit conversions (not only subtypes) on one of the arguments, because then it won't be able to unify the expected type (say `int`) with the type to convert (let's say `float`): [**See on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aa362db286c064d6).